# Get data from database with mysqli_fetch_array and mysqli_fetch_field

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to query data from my database with `mysqli_fetch_array` and `mysqli_fetch_field`, but it's not working at all.
I have the `tbl_student` table like this:

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
| -- | --------- | -------- |
| 1  |  first_A  |  last_A  |
| 2  |  first_B  |  last_B  |
| 3  |  first_C  |  last_C  |
```

PHP code:

```
$query = "select * from tbl_student";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    while ($col = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
        echo $col->name . " = " . $row[$col->name];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

As my wish, I want the result like this one:

```
id = 1
firstname = first_A
lastname = last_A

id = 2
firstname = first_B
lastname = last_B

id = 3
firstname = first_C
lastname = last_C
```

But not, I only have the fist record:

```
id = 1
firstname = first_A
lastname = last_A
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_field` is designed to get detailed information about the fields in the query, not to get information about each field in a record.

Use the following code to get your desired result.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " = " . $value;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that. Thanks you!